# Do I need to load SP.ClientContext More Than Once?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, sp.sod

I have a script that begins as follows:

```
 SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext',auditCheck);

 function auditCheck() {
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
 var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('AuditList');
 var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
 var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
 oListItem.set_item('Title','audit');
 oListItem.update();
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(succeed1, failure1);
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('.button1').click(function() {
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
 var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List1');
 var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
 var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
 oListItem.set_item('Title','ThisTitle');
 oListItem.update();
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(succeed2, failure2);
 });
 }); //end ready
```

Do I need to load `SP.ClientContext` again, using `SP.SOD.executeFunc`, when firing off the button click `$('.button1')` function?

Previously, I was getting an error

> Object does not support this action SP.ClientContext.

But after adding `SP.SOD.executeFunc`, it seems to be okay. The strange thing is I tested in two user groups: Full Permissions and Read Only.

The Read Only group got the error but when I moved them to the Full Perm group, they no longer got the error. This was PRIOR to adding in the `SP.SOD.executeFunc`. AFTER adding the `SP.SOD.excuteFunc`, I added the users back to the READ ONLY group and the error no longer occurs. I'm guessing the group exchange didn't have anything to do with it but it was more of a timing issue.

However, I do want to make sure that `SP.ClientContext` is loaded for all functions calling on it.

Answer (score 0):

We get error `Object does not support this action SP.ClientContext` OR `SP.ClientContext is undefined` when the code that uses the ClientContext object runs even before loading `SP.JS`.

This happens because The `SP.JS` file has the `ClientContext` object used for representing the context of SharePoint Objects and operations.

SO you just need to make sure that `SP.JS` gets loaded properly before custom JavaScript will be executing that uses ClientContext object. There is no need load SP.ClientContext again, using SP.SOD.executeFunc.

Refer below code for better understanding on how to use `SP.SOD.executeFunc` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext',readyFunction);
});

function readyFunction(){

    auditCheck();
    $('.button1').click(btnClickHandler);

}

function auditCheck() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('AuditList');
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Title','audit');
    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(succeed1, failure1);
}

function succeed1(){
    // auditCheck success handler
}

function failure1(){
    // auditCheck failure handler
}


//button click handler
function btnClickHandler(){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List1');
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Title','ThisTitle');
    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(succeed2, failure2);
}


function succeed2(){
    // btnClickHandler success handler
}

function failure2(){
    // btnClickHandler failure handler
}
```

Comment: Rohit: So the way I have it written now, will that work okay? I want the audit function to fire off when the SP.ClientContext loads. The audit function is the first function listed. Is that enough to cover any other functions in doc.ready that are referencing the ClientContext when a user clicks a button?

Comment: @JackSki You code should also work fine. Because your `auditCheck` function will get called after `SP.JS` gets loaded properly. And for the button click handler, by the time button click event handler gets called (user clicks on button), `SP.JS` generally get loaded fully as it gets enough time. But it is always better to make sure the SharePoint script file `SP.JS` is loaded before your code runs(that uses ClientContext object) .

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all your functions inside a **mainFunction** and call it once in your `SP.SOD.executeFunc` :

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext',mainFunction );

function mainFunction(){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button1').click(createList);
  });
  auditCheck();
}

function auditCheck() {
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
 var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('AuditList');
 var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
 var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
 oListItem.set_item('Title','audit');
 oListItem.update();
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(succeed1, failure1);
 }

function createList(){
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
 var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List1');
 var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
 var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
 oListItem.set_item('Title','ThisTitle');
 oListItem.update();
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(succeed2, failure2);
}
```